# Capture event for YUI light box close

Tags: javascript, yui

I have a light box (YUI) in my application. Upon closing of this lightbox by making use of the 'x' at the upper right side, I need to perform a set of actions. For this I need to capture the event that gets triggered when the lightbox is closed. Can some one please help?
Note - I did some research online and even went through the YUI js files but could not figure out a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately the Lightbox module in the YUI Gallery is very much outdated and it's no using any of the YUI components that would let you react to the lightbox being closed. I'd recommend that you use [AUI's ImageViewer component](http://alloyui.com/tutorials/image-viewer/) which is pretty similar to a Lightbox. It allows you to listen to an event that signals the closing of the viewer like this:

```
YUI().use('aui-image-viewer', function(Y) {
  var imageViewer = new Y.ImageViewer({
    links: '#gallery a'
  });
  imageViewer.render();
  imageViewer.on('visibleChange', function (Y) {
    // if e.newVal is false, then the image viewer is being hidden
    if (!e.newVal) {
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It might be possible to do something like this:

```
Y.one('#buttonNavClose').on('click', doSomething);
```

buttonNavClose being the id of the close button node.